# How to deploy a Vyper smart contract? Remix fails to compile

Tags: solidity, remix, vyper

I have been trying all the solutions and tutorials I found on the Internet, with no success. Remix fails to compile vyper smart contracts in local and remote. How to make it work?

Comment: Hi there. What's the error?

Comment: Using Remix IDE, I only see the error icon next to the Vyper icon when I try to compile. Is there another way to deploy a contract written in Vyper? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the public Vyper server is down. This video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5M5p6SnW-Og) explains how to get your local server running. You could follow his instructions, or if you have Mac, you could try what I did:

```
$ brew install gmp leveldb
```

Next I activated a Python 3.9 virtualenv and then

```
$ python3.9 -m pip install vyper
```

Then I could successfully compile Vyper files like so

```
$ vyper MyContract.vy   
0x7159c2e62 ...
```

... and start a Vyper server locally like this

```
$ vyper-serve 
Listening on http://localhost:8000
```

Then in the Remix IDE in the Vyper plugin tab you click on the "LOCAL COMPILER" tab (make sure the port number is correct given the output of the last command) and you should be able to compile successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can run compile locally using vyper module.

```
pip install vyper==0.3.1
```

You can read more about [vyper](https://github.com/GrandSchtroumpf/vyper-remix).

Start the vyper server by following command

```
vyper-serve -b localhost:8000
```

Verify the vyper-serve is working fine by opening localhost:8000 in browser.

But you will also need [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/download) for this to work.

You can run ngrok with the following command

```
ngrok http http://localhost:8000
```

This will generate a public link e.g. **https://4b47-223-190-93-108.in.ngrok.io**

This link can be used as a local compiler in Remix IDE.

*PS: It does not show compilation error line by line as Solidity Compiler in Remix IDE*

Answer (score 0):

I use the brownie framework for Vyper smart contracts.

https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploy.html

Comment: As of late 2022, Brownie is dormant.  Bugs are not being fixed.  Many people report they cannot install it on Windows.  I used it to learn simple Vyper contracts on Mac.  But it doesn't provide runtime error messages, when one contract fails calling another contract.  YMMV.

Comment: Apeworx is a good alternative.